# Nullable value types

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, value-type

If a value type is declared nullable, how should I take precautions for this? I.e. if in the constructor I have:

```
public Point3 ( Point3 source )
{
    this.X = source.X;
    this.Y = source.Y;
    this.Z = source.Z;
}
```

would it fail, if source was null?

Answer (score 10):

I don't see the possibility of `Point3` being `null` if it's a value type. Don't you miss a question mark? And if you really mean `Point3?`, then you should access it like:

```
public Point3 ( Point3? source )
{
    this.X = source.Value.X;
    this.Y = source.Value.Y;
    this.Z = source.Value.Z;
}
```

and in this case, the `Value` property will throw an exception if it's `null`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the type has to be written as nullable. I thought any value type can be declared like that.

Comment: No, value types can't be null. Nullable types was a feature added to  .NET 2.0 to fill this gap for value types. You have to explicitly use a nullable variable to be able to set it as null.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to have a constructor like you have above to give the users the ability to declare Point3 as nullable, right?
 Can I also both include nullable constructors and regular ones for value types?

Comment: No, it's not related to the value type. ANY value type can be declared as nullable by adding a question mark. In fact, the nullable type is really Nullable<T> and not T.

Comment: Thanks. I have to read about them I think. I thought it's done if the developer gives nullable support as well as non-nullable support.

Comment: Depends on the meaning of support. For declaring and using them, absolutely not. But it's up to the developer to add auxiliary methods that work on nullable version (get a nullable parameter, for example). In that case, just like any type, it should be explicitly declared as such.

Answer (score 3):

The caller of this method will not be able to pass in a nullable point, since the method takes a regular point, not a Nullable one. Therefore, you don't need to worry about Point being null in your constructor code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would fail if `source` was null.

You'll have to decide what the correct behavior should be if `source` is null.  You might just throw an exception.

```
public Point3 ( Point3? source )
{
    if (source == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    this.X = source.Value.X;
    this.Y = source.Value.Y;
    this.Z = source.Value.Z;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to accept `null` values for `source`, just keep the method as you have it in your example.  That method doesn't accept a `Nullable<Point3>`, so you don't have to worry about it being `null` in that case.

Comment: Nullable<T> doesn't have properties X, Y, Z... You should either use a cast or the Value property...

Answer (score 1):

If `source` was a `Point3?` it wouldn't be a `Point3`. So as far as I know, it would fail compile time. To send in a `Point3?` you would have to use `.Value`, which would throw an exception I believe if it was null.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Point3(Point3? source) { 
       this.X = source.GetValueOrDefault().X; 
        this.Y = source.GetValueOrDefault().Y;
        this.Z = source.GetValueOrDefault().Z; 
    }
```